# How to run php jobs regularly in my Amazon EC2 server?

Tags: php

I have a Amazon EC2 server.
And I would like to run php jobs every 1 hours to get the latest information from websites and insert them into database.
But I am not good at server.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this [URL](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/), you call crontab from the shell and to execute every hour, add the "00" at the beginning, point to the location of PHP and the script you want to run.

```
# crontab -e
00 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/dir/myscript.php
```

Answer (score 1):

As for any Linux server, use crontab.

On the terminal (SSH) :

```
crontab -e
```

[See the man page for cron](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?crontab%205)